# How do you manage to liquefy a gas by applying only pressure?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws, pressure, vapor-pressure

How can you liquefy a gas by applying only pressure? To increase the pressure of a gas you need a compressor, and when the compressor does work on the gas , it will increase his pressure but at the same time it will increase his temperature, and it will still be a gas. To become a liquid it will need to have his temperature decreased bellow his boiling point at the correspondent pressure. So how can u liquefy a gas by just incresing his pressure?

I read that in butane lighters, the butane is liquid inside the lighter because it is at a pressure of around 2 bar and at ambient temperature the butane is liquid if it has a pressure of 2 bar. But isnt that 2 bar the vapour pressure inside the lighter? If the temperature increases the pressure/vapour pressure inside will increase and if the temperature decresses the pressure/ vapour pressure will decrease and the butane will still stay at liquid state. So i dont undersand why people say that the butane is liquid because of the increase in pressure, because at the ambient temperature to become a liquid needs to be at 2 bar. And the butane that is put inside the lighter is liquid but is it already at 2 bar or is at any pressure?

Answer (score 1):

First, not all gases can be liquefied at room temperature by increasing pressure. If the gas is above the [critical temperature](https://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/liquids/critical.html), it cannot be liquefied by *any* increase in pressure; it becomes a [supercritical fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid). Supercritical fluids have some of the properties of a gas (e.g. diffusing through fine openings), ans some of liquids (e.g. dissolving solids and liquids). For that reason, supercritical $\ce{CO2}$ makes an excellent dry-cleaning agent.

Second, the [supercritical point for butane is 152 °C at a pressure of ~3,800 kPa](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/gas-critical-temperature-pressure-d_161.html). At that temperature, a bit above boiling water, the pressure in the lighter would be about 38 times atmospheric pressure... if it hadn't yet vented its contents.

As for the manufacture of the lighter, butane *could* easily be liquefied by cooling to it's boiling point at standard pressure, ~0 °C, easily reached in a freezer (which is why butane is not the best fuel for camping in the snow). However, since the fumes must be contained anyway, a pressurized system is needed, and two atmospheres pressure is easily handled. The same for liquefied propane, which is pumped at room temperature into steel tanks.

Comment: But what do you mean by "gases can be liquefied at room temperature by increasing pressure"? if i increase the pressure of a gas at room temperature i will also increase his temperature and it will remain a gas, only if i decrease his temperature after increasing his pressure it will liquefy. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: It depends on the phase diagram. Some gases can be liquefied by increasing pressure alone, without removing heat of compression, others require cooling, and yet others, such as hydrogen, are so far above critical temperature that they must be chilled considerably before they can be liquefied at all. Consider liquefied butane in a sealed container: heating it to a temperature below 152 °C will increase the pressure, but does not cause the butane to completely vaporize.

Answer (score -2):

As one increases the pressure, the volume occupied by the gas decreases. Like you said, the temperature should increase with increasing pressure. Equivalently you could say that the thermal energy of the molecules of the gas has increased which manifests itself in increased collisions and vibrations of the constituent molecules. The decrement in volume serves as a constraint as this means that we are physically bringing those molecules closer. All this leads to increased interactions between those molecules and you get a liquid.

P.S. : I didnt read the supporting question as I am sleepy and therefore less motivated to read that.
P.P.S : This is my first answer here, so I am sorry for the construction of this answer. If you find any mistakes, kindly notify me (I'm not sure how it works).
Enjoy!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. What do people mean by  "gases can be liquefied at room temperature by increasing pressure"? if i increase the pressure of a gas at room temperature i will also increase his temperature and it will remain a gas, only if i decrease his temperature after increasing his pressure it will liquefy. Am I thinking correctly?